# xero_python Create Timesheet

Tags: python, xero-api

I'm working off `xero_python` app example seen [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-python-oauth2-app) and attempting to make a `create_timesheet` route.

So far I've not found any material on creating timesheets using `xero_python.payrollau` so wondering if anyone here might have some experience with this?

I've shared my current example as an issue for the [above git](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-python-oauth2-app/issues/7).  I keep hitting various hurdles such as timesheet ids not being accepted/etc.

If anyone has been successful with the above I would be super grateful for some guidance here.